# How do i know the YUV format from android camera onPreviewFrame?

Tags: android, android-camera, yuv

I want to know the yuv data format from `onPreviewFrame`. As we know, we can set the `parameter.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21)` before `startPreview`. After setting that, is the format from `onPreviewFrame` NV21 ? Is that suitable for all android phone?

Comment: Don't be surprised if some forked devices will not default to NV21, and even fail to set this format.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting `parameter.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21)` the format in `onPreviewFrame` will be NV21 as it is supported in all devices (YV12 is also supported in all devices, according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewFormat(int)) ). Also, NV21 is the default if you don't set it.

In case you are not sure which preview format is the current one you can query the camera parameters with `parameter.getPreviewFormat()` .

Comment: Thanks. In fact, i need to ensure what i set is the actual preview format.

Comment: It will be when using NV21.